# print line started by "F served.." in a multiple output file using "sed command"

Tags: linux, sed, ksh

I developed a script using `sed` to retrieve lines starting by text `F servedM..` from a given multilines file :

- I have an input.txt file of 100000 line
- I want to generate an `output.txt` containing all line starting by `F servedMyd` and all lines starting by `F servedPuid`.

I am using ksh on Red Hat 7.4.

Below I give the code I tried.

```
#!/bin/ksh
input.txt=$1
while read line
do
sed "/^F servedMyd/p" $input.txt >> output.txt
sed "/^F servedPuid/p" $input.txt >> output.txt
done < $input.txt
exit 0
```

With this code, I didn't get any output. I expected having an output file with the following structure:

[image]

Comment: What is `input.txt=$1` supposed to do?

Comment: What's wrong with `grep '^F served\(My\|Pui\)d' input.txt`?

Comment: "What is input.txt=$1 supposed to do?"  I tried to get the input file name

Comment: But `input.txt` is not a valid variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script is unnecessary, a single line of `sed` should be sufficient:

```
sed -n '/^F served\(My\|Pui\)d/p' foo > bar
```

Or `grep`:

```
grep '^F served\(My\|Pui\)d' foo > bar
```

Or:

```
grep -E '^F served(My|Pui)d' foo > bar
```

Comment: Perhaps  `sed '/^F served\(Myd\|Puid\)/w fileOut' fileIn`